# Extract equal distance points from array - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of X,Y coordinates (closed object) of different sizes (`numArrayLength`, e.g., 25) and I wish to extract specific equally distances points based on a changeable number (`subSetNum`).

I have few issues that I will appreciate a help:

- As the 1st and last content in the array are similar how can I avoid this point duplication?
- I have a calculation issue, for example when I set `subSetNum` to 8 I get 1     4     7    10    13    16    19    22    25 but when it is set to 7 I get   1     5     9    13    17    21    25. Why?
- Is there a way to do it without the loop?

Thanks.

Script:

```
clc;
clear;
numArrayLength=25; % Length of the array
subSetNum=8; % Selection points

numArray=rand(numArrayLength,2); % Array declaration, Y coordinate

numArray(numArrayLength)=numArray(1) %% Close object so Y(1) and Y(numArrayLength) are the same
numArray = numArray(1:end-1,:)

extractPoint=round(numArrayLength/subSetNum); %Number of points to extract
extractPointIndex=1:extractPoint:numArrayLength %Array index to extract

for n = 1:size(extractPointIndex)
   numArray(extractPointIndex())
end
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of inputs and desired outputs for some simple case? I'm having trouble understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What's wrong with the way it's being calculated?  The difference between 8 and 7 is because of the `round` statement.  That will push it over so that you're sampling from one over to the right.  What you're doing here is fine.  I would like to clarify that by "equal distances", what you actually mean is that you want to sample at every nth point so you will have `subsetNum` points.  This requires that you sample every `n = round(numArrayLength / subsetNum)` points.  Using "distance" in this context is confusing, which is the point @Dev-iL is making.

Comment: If you also want to remove the last point from the sampling, simply remove it before subsampling as this is a closed contour of points.

Comment: I removed the last point in the script. Still i do not get the right amount of points. Any idea how I can get nth points with the most close proximity to equal distance and without the last point.

Comment: Try `extractPointIndex = round(linspace(1, numArrayLength - 1, subSetNum));`